# Help in list.phtml coding

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml

Just found a kinda working code

```
<?php 
$qtd = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getQty();

if ( $qtd == 999 ) {  ?> 

    <button type="button" title="SOB ORÇAMENTO" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button_green btn_cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getUrl(contacts) ?>')"><span><span>SOB ORÇAMENTO</span></span></button> 
<?php  } 
elseif ( $qtd == 0 ) {  ?>

    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>

<?php } 
else {  ?>

     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>

 <?php } ?>
```

this is basically what I want, I think it's easy to understand, but I still have some kind of error, the title "sob orçamento" goes even when the quantity it's 0

the elseif it's not working somehow

Comment: just a note: your priceHTML is a display friendly element to show the price. It contains a lot more than the price. So you wont be able to test easily for a value. Price is complicated because of customer groups, bulk buy rules, offers etc. and it is a calculated thing.
What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Clear Your question list.hptml or list.phtml

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/119637)

Comment: @iphigenie im trying to do kinda what cart2quote does, but only when my price is empty or negative.

Comment: @jon did you mean you always get enter into first if condition regardless qty is  999 or 0 ?

Comment: That's right @shashank

Comment: the text of your question has changed so much it's hard to keep up ;)
in your example quantity is a lot easier than price to tests on - price is dealt with in a separate template because of taxes, offers etc. which need extra context. You could take that content and find the amount in it, or use javascript after the page is loaded to change the text of the button.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
$html = $_this->getPriceHtml();
<?php elseif($html==''): ?>
<h3><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(contacts) ?>">
    <span>The different Text</span>
</a></h3>
```